# Google Drive Javascript API: get all files recursively and put them in array before calling another function

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I want to use the **Google Drive Javascript API** to get all video files in a specific folder and its subfolders. After the list is generated, I want to call another function to format and display the data (this part is working fine).

I understand that the Drive API only supports searching for immediate children, so I have to recursively search when I hit folder types. This is fine.

The issue that I'm facing is that this is all happening asynchronously, and I don't want to analyze or display any data until the array of videos has been fully populated.

How can I call a function only after all of the recursive calls to `gapi.client.drive.files.list` have completed?

```
  /**
   * Get all the video files from the parent folder and child folders
   */
  var videos = [];
  function listFiles(parentFolder) {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'pageSize': 100,
      'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, thumbnailLink, createdTime, parents)",
      'supportsTeamDrives': true,
      'orderBy': "createdTime desc",
      'includeTeamDriveItems': true,
      'q': "'" + parentFolder + "' in parents and trashed = false"
    }).then(function(response) {
      var files = response.result.files;
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          if (file.mimeType.includes("video")) {
            videos.push(file);
          } else if (file.mimeType.includes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")){
            /* This is the recursive call to get child folder videos */
            listFiles(file.id);
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      /* I want to run these only after all recursive calls complete and add videos to videos[] */ 
      updateStats();
      displayVideos();
    });
  }
```

What is the best way to proceed? Can you help? :)